Trigger google places api on button click instead of input change
I'm working on a React.js project using Material-UI (MUI), and I have a component where users need to enter their address. To minimize API costs, I want to trigger the Google Places API only when the user clicks a button, rather than on every input change.
Currently, I've set it up so that the API call happens when the button is clicked, but I'm running into two issues:
The Google Places autocomplete dropdown doesn't appear immediately after the button click; it only shows up if the user clicks the input field again.
Even after implementing this, the Google API continues to make requests on every input change, which is what I'm trying to avoid.
How can I configure the component so that the Google Places API is triggered only once when the button is clicked, and the autocomplete dropdown shows up immediately, without any additional clicks or unwanted API calls?
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  useMediaQuery,
  Box,
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  TextField,
  CircularProgress,
  Fade,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
} from "@mui/material";

function Modal({ open, setOpen }) {
  const isUnder600px = useMediaQuery("(max-width:600px)");
  const isUnder1000px = useMediaQuery("(max-width:1000px)");
  const licensePlateInputRef = useRef(null);
  const addressInputRef = useRef(null);
  const autocompleteRef = useRef(null);

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    licensePlate: "",
    address: "",
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [isLicensePlateInputDisabled, setIsLicensePlateInputDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [showCloseButton, setShowCloseButton] = useState(true);
  const [inputKey, setInputKey] = useState(Date.now());

  let maxWidth;
  if (isUnder600px) {
    maxWidth = "xs";
  } else if (isUnder1000px) {
    maxWidth = "sm";
  } else {
    maxWidth = "md";
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open && licensePlateInputRef.current) {
      licensePlateInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [open]);

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason === "backdropClick") return;
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSearch = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setShowCloseButton(false);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setShowForm(true);
      setIsLicensePlateInputDisabled(true);
    }, 1500);
  };

  const handleSearchAddress = () => {
    setInputKey(Date.now());

    if (
      window.google &&
      addressInputRef.current &&
      !autocompleteRef.current
    ) {
      autocompleteRef.current = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        addressInputRef.current,
        {
          types: ["address"],
          componentRestrictions: { country: "it" },
        }
      );

      autocompleteRef.current.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        const place = autocompleteRef.current.getPlace();
        if (place && place.formatted_address) {
          setData((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            address: place.formatted_address,
          }));
        }
      });

      addressInputRef.current.focus();
      const inputEvent = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
      addressInputRef.current.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSearch();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      fullWidth={true}
      maxWidth={maxWidth}
      PaperProps={{
        sx: {
          maxWidth: showForm ? maxWidth : "400px",
          width: "100%",
          overflow: "visible",
        },
      }}
    >
      <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
        {loading ? "Searching..." : "New Search"}
      </DialogTitle>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <DialogContent>
          {loading ? (
            <Box
              sx={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                padding: "8px 0",
              }}
            >
              <CircularProgress />
            </Box>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: maxWidth === "md" ? "row" : "column",
                  marginBottom: "8px",
                  marginTop: "8px",
                }}
              >
                <TextField
                  id={"licensePlate-input"}
                  disabled={isLicensePlateInputDisabled}
                  size="small"
                  label="License Plate"
                  name="licensePlate"
                  value={data.licensePlate}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  fullWidth={!showForm}
                  inputRef={licensePlateInputRef}
                  autoFocus
                />
                {showForm && (
                  <Fade in={showForm}>
                    <Box
                      sx={{
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        marginTop: maxWidth === "md" ? "0" : "8px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <Box ml={maxWidth === "md" ? 4 : 0}>
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={
                            <Checkbox
                              sx={{
                                marginBottom: "3px",
                                margin: maxWidth === "xs" ? "8px 0" : " 0",
                              }}
                              defaultChecked={false}
                            />
                          }
                          label="Via Roma 56,199, Giugliano in Campania Na"
                        />
                        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                          <TextField
                            id={`address-input-${inputKey}`}
                            size="small"
                            label="Residential Address"
                            sx={{ width: "360px", marginRight: "16px" }}
                            error={false}
                            helperText={""}
                            value={data.address}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            name="address"
                            InputProps={{
                              inputRef: addressInputRef,
                            }}
                          />
                          <Button
                            sx={{ maxHeight: "36px" }}
                            variant="contained"
                            onClick={handleSearchAddress}
                          >
                            {(maxWidth === "md") | "sm"
                              ? "Search Address"
                              : "Search"}
                          </Button>
                        </Box>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                  </Fade>
                )}
              </Box>
            </>
          )}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
        </DialogActions>
      </form>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default Modal;




you try below code
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    import {
      useMediaQuery,
      Box,
      Button,
      Dialog,
      DialogActions,
      DialogContent,
      DialogTitle,
      TextField,
      CircularProgress,
      Fade,
      FormControlLabel,
      Checkbox,
    } from "@mui/material";

    function Modal({ open, setOpen }) {
      const isUnder600px = useMediaQuery("(max-width:600px)");
      const isUnder1000px = useMediaQuery("(max-width:1000px)");
      const licensePlateInputRef = useRef(null);
      const addressInputRef = useRef(null);
      const autocompleteRef = useRef(null);

      const [data, setData] = useState({
        licensePlate: "",
        address: "",
      });
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
      const [isLicensePlateInputDisabled, setIsLicensePlateInputDisabled] = useState(false);
      const [showCloseButton, setShowCloseButton] = useState(true);
      const [inputKey, setInputKey] = useState(Date.now());

      let maxWidth;
      if (isUnder600px) {
        maxWidth = "xs";
      } else if (isUnder1000px) {
        maxWidth = "sm";
      } else {
        maxWidth = "md";
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        if (open && licensePlateInputRef.current) {
          licensePlateInputRef.current.focus();
        }
      }, [open]);

      const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason && reason === "backdropClick") return;
        setOpen(false);
      };

      const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setData((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          [name]: value,
        }));
      };

      const handleSearch = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setShowCloseButton(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLoading(false);
          setShowForm(true);
          setIsLicensePlateInputDisabled(true);
        }, 1500);
      };

      const handleSearchAddress = () => {
        setInputKey(Date.now()); // Force re-render
        
        if (window.google && addressInputRef.current) {
          if (!autocompleteRef.current) {
            autocompleteRef.current = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              addressInputRef.current,
              {
                types: ["address"],
                componentRestrictions: { country: "it" },
              }
            );

            autocompleteRef.current.addListener("place_changed", () => {
              const place = autocompleteRef.current.getPlace();
              if (place && place.formatted_address) {
                setData((prev) => ({
                  ...prev,
                  address: place.formatted_address,
                }));
              }
            });
          }

          // Trigger the autocomplete dropdown manually
          const inputEvent = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
          addressInputRef.current.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
          
          // Set focus to the input field to ensure the dropdown shows up
          addressInputRef.current.focus();
        }
      };

      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleSearch();
      };

      return (
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
          fullWidth={true}
          maxWidth={maxWidth}
          PaperProps={{
            sx: {
              maxWidth: showForm ? maxWidth : "400px",
              width: "100%",
              overflow: "visible",
            },
          }}
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
            {loading ? "Searching..." : "New Search"}
          </DialogTitle>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <DialogContent>
              {loading ? (
                <Box
                  sx={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    padding: "8px 0",
                  }}
                >
                  <CircularProgress />
                </Box>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      display: "flex",
                      flexDirection: maxWidth === "md" ? "row" : "column",
                      marginBottom: "8px",
                      marginTop: "8px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <TextField
                      id={"licensePlate-input"}
                      disabled={isLicensePlateInputDisabled}
                      size="small"
                      label="License Plate"
                      name="licensePlate"
                      value={data.licensePlate}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      fullWidth={!showForm}
                      inputRef={licensePlateInputRef}
                      autoFocus
                    />
                    {showForm && (
                      <Fade in={showForm}>
                        <Box
                          sx={{
                            display: "flex",
                            flexDirection: "column",
                            marginTop: maxWidth === "md" ? "0" : "8px",
                          }}
                        >
                          <Box ml={maxWidth === "md" ? 4 : 0}>
                            <FormControlLabel
                              control={
                                <Checkbox
                                  sx={{
                                    marginBottom: "3px",
                                    margin: maxWidth === "xs" ? "8px 0" : " 0",
                                  }}
                                  defaultChecked={false}
                                />
                              }
                              label="Via Roma 56,199, Giugliano in Campania Na"
                            />
                            <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                              <TextField
                                id={`address-input-${inputKey}`}
                                size="small"
                                label="Residential Address"
                                sx={{ width: "360px", marginRight: "16px" }}
                                error={false}
                                helperText={""}
                                value={data.address}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                name="address"
                                InputProps={{
                                  inputRef: addressInputRef,
                                }}
                              />
                              <Button
                                sx={{ maxHeight: "36px" }}
                                variant="contained"
                                onClick={handleSearchAddress}
                              >
                                {(maxWidth === "md" || maxWidth === "sm") ? "Search Address" : "Search"}
                              </Button>
                            </Box>
                          </Box>
                        </Box>
                      </Fade>
                    )}
                  </Box>
                </>
              )}
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
            </DialogActions>
          </form>
        </Dialog>
      );
    }

    export default Modal;


unfortunately the issue persists. The button triggers the google api, as it did before, but the dropdown does not show up. I still have to click again the input for the results dropdown to show up. Also google triggers api requests after every focus or change of the input.

in handleSearchAddress put below code after    addressInputRef.current.focus();
code->
const clickEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", { bubbles: true });
addressInputRef.current.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

Unfortunately it is still not working as expected. I believe google is preventing the flow to work this way. As for google it is important to trigger api request on every input change rather than limiting them to button search clicks.
